# Remove a member from an object?

Tags: php, class, attributes

Is there a simple way to remove a member from an object?  Not just set it to null, but actually remove it.

Thanks! :)

Edit: I've already tried unset(), and setting the member variable to null obviously doesn't work.  I suppose I could convert the object to an array, then remove the array key in question, and convert back to an object, but blech...  There's got to be an easier way!

Comment: I'm thinking you might want to look into some possibilities offered by Reflection. Not 100% on that, but the Reflection classes provide some comprehensive features. Also, curious; *why*?

Comment: How do you check whether it was removed? isset? var_dump?

Comment: I'm using RedBean in my persistence layer; it creates a column for every member on the Bean (an object).  There's a leftover member variable from a utility function that I use; rather than rewrite the utility function, I'd rather just remove the member variable in question.

Comment: Ah, RedBean looks nifty. Shall investigate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using RedBean. Just checked it out. And these bean objects don't have actual properties.

```
unset($bean->field);
```

Does not work, because `->field` is a **virtual attribute**. It does not exist in the class. Rather it resides in the `protected $bean->properties[]` which you cannot access. RedBean only implements the magic methods `__get` and `__set` for retrieving and setting attributes.

This is why the `unset()` does not work. It unsets a property that never existed at that location.

Comment: Just Googled this again, and my answer came up... Ha! :)  For anyone else having this issue, you might try patching your RedBean to allow calling unset() on bean properties.  Insert this after the __set() magic method:
 /* Magic Setter. Unsets the value for a specific property. */
 public function __unset( $property ) {
  unset($this->properties[$property]);
 }

Answer (score 11):

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->answer = 42;
print_r($obj);
unset($obj->answer);
print_r($obj);
```

[Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/FNFvO). Are you sure you 're doing it right?

**Update:**

[It also works](http://ideone.com/3euVc) for properties defined in classes:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = 42;
}

$obj = new Foo;
print_r($obj);
unset($obj->bar);
print_r($obj);
```

Comment: yeah, that works fine for me under PHP 5.3.2 too. Also worked on an actual defined class (including removing defined members).

Comment: It's so weird that it's not working for me!  I think I'm on PHP 5.1.2 if that changes anything... :P

Comment: Is it a dynamic property, ala Jon's "answer", or one that is hard-coded in the class definition?  Those are impossible to remove.  why do you need to remove it?

Comment: I believe it is a dynamic property, but I'm not certain.  From my memory of the utility function that created the member in question, it was created as a property on an array first, and then this array was converted to an object.  (As for why I need to remove the member, please see my comment on the initial question above) :)

Comment: Great answer that will help many people that land on this page via Google.  Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 5):

within you object you can define a magic method called `__unset`

```
class Test
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __unset($key)
    {
        unset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}
```

And Jon summed up the other factors nicely.

Answer (score 3):

RedBean has a removeProperty method on beans.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  This should be helpful to newcomers to this question.  I believe this was unavailable in RedBean circa early 2011 (it is now almost exactly three years later :) ).  In fact, back in the day (as you can see in my Jan 17 '13 comment above), I added a magic setter to allow unset() to be used directly on the bean itself.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Comment: Hi, mario!  I'm using it to unset the member variable named 'old_index' in this manner: "unset($c->old_index);"

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, nor in the Runkit module do I see a way to accomplish that, even if ways to remove [methods/functions/constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit.php) exist.

Answer (score 1):

With RedBean 4 you can use

```
unset($bean->someproperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to unset the property merely because you **do not want it stored in the database?**

If so, just declare the property as `private` in the class.

Kudos to this answer: [Not saving property of a php-redbean to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869584/not-saving-property-of-a-php-redbean-to-database/17869726#17869726)

Comment: TBH, I asked this question nearly four years ago, so I don't recall.  Regardless, thanks for your answer!  Perhaps it will help someone else! :)