# Not saving property of a php-redbean to database

Tags: php, database, orm, redbean

I'm using Redbean as an ORM for my php-application.

Every user (employee in this situation), has to have a password in order to login, and I thought i'd generate one for them, so they don't have to type it in the form.

Obviously, this means they all have to have a salt, and the only password stored should be the hash value of the actual password. Because of that I have to send the password to the user (otherwise they won't know it :D), and thus have to have it as a property of the object, without saving it for the database.

A clever place to generate passwords would be in the model, so that it basically does it by itself for every new employee (user), therefor I created this model:

```
class Model_employee extends RedBean_SimpleModel
{
  public function dispense()
  {
    $this->salt = cypher::getIV(32);
    $this->tempPassword = cypher::getIV(8);
    $this->password = md5($this->salt . $this->password);
  }

  public function update()
  {
    unset($this->tempPassword);
  }
}
```

The generating password in `dispense()` works fine. The `update()` is supposed to be run right before the bean is saved, and so it is (if I null the property it is saved as null), however, the tempPassword is still saved, even if I unset it (the column is also created, even if I store it as null).

Basically, the question boils down to this: **How do I get rid of the `tempPassword` property, so that it is not saved to the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that someone else just asked that exact question a couple of days ago, in the [readBean forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redbeanorm/uNIrEB3Ev6Y).

Basically, redbean won't store private properties of any class extension.

The solution was then quite simple:

```
class Model_employee extends RedBean_SimpleModel
{
  private $tempPassword;
  public function dispense()
  {
    $this->salt = cypher::getIV(32);
    $this->tempPassword = cypher::getIV(8);
    $this->password = md5($this->salt . $this->password);
  }
}
```

This won't store the password in the database, nor create the column.
Of course, I have to add a getter() if I want to read the password, but the above solves the immediate problem :)